# Actualizar usuario a través de un form para database

Tags: javascript, nodejs, base-de-datos

Estoy tratando de actualizar la información de un usuario pero me da que lo que envió por el form es null o undefined (error: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object). Puedo crear el usuario, eso esta andando, pero esta parte me esta costando

Database.js:

```
async function edit(user, id){
    try{
        await query (`UPDATE users SET ? WHERE id=?`, [Object.keys(user), Object.values(user),id])
        return {user, success: true}
    }catch(error){
        return {error, success: false}
    }
}
```

Controladores:

```
async update(user, id){
        const users = await edit(user, id)
        return users
    }
```

Rutas:

```
router.post('/edit', async (req, res)=>{
    const id = req.body.id
    const user = req.body.user
    const result = await userController.update(user, id)
    return console.log(result)
    
})
```

HTML:

```
<form action="/edit" method="POST">
      <h3>Editar usuario</h3>
      <label for="nombre">Nombre</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="bordeinterior" ><br>
      <label for="date">Fecha de nacimiento</label><br>
      <input type="date" name="birthday" id="" class="bordeinterior" ><br>
      <label for="email">Email</label><br>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="" class="bordeinterior" ><br>
      <label for="genero">Genero</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="gender" id="" class="bordeinterior" ><br>
      <label for="profesion">Profesión</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="profession" id="" class="bordeinterior" ><br>
      <input type="submit" class="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Primero, en el formulario no estás enviando ID de usuario, eso ya es motivo para generar error al querer actualizar. Después, dudo que en la consulta se remplace `?` usando `Object.keys(user)` y pueda quedar en un formato `columna1 = 'valor1', columna2 = 'valor2', etc`

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar no se envia el **id** actual del usuario a modificar, asi que este **id** se puede enviar en la ruta de la peticion `http` con el cual puedes usar  [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) con el metodo `PUT` como se ve en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';
const userForm = document.querySelector('#user-form');
const currentId = 10;

userForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = new FormData(e.target);
  const user = {
    id: currentId,
    name: data.get('name'),
    birthday: data.get('birthday'),
    email: data.get('email'),
    gender: data.get('gender'),
    profession: data.get('profession'),
  };

  console.log(user);

  fetch(`${API_URL}/api/user/${user.id}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user),
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="user-form">
  <h3>Editar usuario</h3>
  <label for="nombre">Nombre</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="name" value="bladimir" class="bordeinterior" /><br />
  <label for="date">Fecha de nacimiento</label><br />
  <input type="date" name="birthday" value="2022-12-12" class="bordeinterior" /><br />
  <label for="email">Email</label><br />
  <input type="email" name="email" value="bladimir@gmail.com" class="bordeinterior" /><br />
  <label for="genero">Genero</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="gender" value="male" class="bordeinterior" /><br />
  <label for="profesion">Profesión</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="profession" value="developer" class="bordeinterior" /><br />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" />
</form>
```

La mejor forma de usar una `API REST` es accediendo a sus metodos como `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc. es por eso que agregar **'user/edit'** a tu ruta no hace mucho sentido, es por eso que cuando declares tus rutas en tu `app.js` manten el nombre global `this.app.use('/api/user', userRoutes)` y para las operaciones usar los metodos que tienen router.

Tambien es bueno usar el status en el response como se ve en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
router.route.put('/:id', async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const id = req.body.id;
    const user = req.body;
    const [
      [row]
    ] = await query(`SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?`, [id]);

    if (!row) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: '❌No se pudo actualizar el usuario, por que no existe. ',
      });
    }

    await query(`UPDATE user SET ? WHERE id=?`, [user, id]);

    return res.status(200).json({
      message: 'Usuario actualizado correctamente! ',
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('❌Ocurrio un error:', error);
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: error,
    });
  }
});
```